# Generate lists of all columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has 40+ columns. I would like to generate lists with each list containing values from one column. Here is how I tried to do it

```
cols= df.columns
cols = cols.tolist()
for col in cols:
    col = df.col.tolist()
```

Error:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'

So it seems loop is trying to find 'col' in dataframe rather then taking the item from list 'cols'.

Using

```
 A = df.A.tolist()
```

Works so I am guessing I am making mistake in loop?

Comment: You mean `df[col].tolist()`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `[]` for select by column name:

```
for col in cols:
    col = df[col].tolist()
```

If need all values in lists is possible create dictionary by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.to_dict(orient='list')
```